# Setting a Camera's Point Of View in SceneKit

Tags: camera, scenekit, scnscene, scncamera

How can I set the SceneKit [**SCNCamera**](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scncamera) properties for 2d views such as:

```
- top view
- bottom view
- front view
- back view
- left side view
- right side view
```

Comment: Do you mean like the default operating four views of a 3D modelling and animation app, like Maya, C4D and 3ds Max?

Comment: No animation just want to set the view in plane view in any directions.

Comment: So it's just one view, and you want to be able to switch between these various views, instantly?

Comment: Right, Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

To change camera (cut), use the [pointOfView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1523982-pointofview?language=objc) property of the [SCNSceneRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerenderer) class.

To set an orthographic projection for the camera (no perspective), check the [usesOrthographicProjection](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scncamera/1436621-usesorthographicprojection) and [orthographicScale](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scncamera/1436612-orthographicscale) properties of the [SCNCamera](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scncamera) class.

Comment: What is the suitable `orthographicScale` for Top View covering whole sceneView sized (1920x1080)?